# How to tell if SQL server is trimming the result if TOP is used?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable
```

How do I tell if the results were cut short, i.e. MyTable actually has more than 10 rows?

Comment: p.s. The reason I am interested in this is that if there are more results, I want to log the fact that the result set was cut short. If I don't add any limit, then the result set could be enormous, which would mean SQL server would grind to a standstill.

Comment: Do TOP 11, and you'll see.

Comment: Query top 11 and only use 10 rows

Comment: @jarlh I would like to avoid doing two queries, as this would double the load on SQL server.

Comment: @Contango: a `select count(*) from MyTable` would be your best choice, that way you know how many rows and it won't add too much extra load the server for simple queries

Comment: @SébastienSevrin: a `COUNT(*)` is a pretty heavy operation if you have to scan a big table! I much prefer the `TOP 11` into a temp-table and then do `TOP 10` on that approach. That said, doing a `TOP` whatever without an `ORDER BY` isn't really correct I think, unless you really don't care which 10 rows you want. Without an `ORDER BY` you probably will most often get the same ones, but once in a while it will be a totally different set. I've learned that one by experience here... (disclaimer, it was not my code =P )

Comment: @Contango, I mean always do TOP 11, then you use 10 rows.

Comment: Never use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`. Things as "top", "bottom", "first" or "last" are undefined if you do not have a natural order on things.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to add a COUNT..OVER column that returns the total rows in the table in the same query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *, COUNT(*) OVER() As TotalRows FROM MyTable
```

This total is calculated *after* the FROM and WHERE clauses are executed, but *before* the TOP clause is applied.

Comment: However, I think I would also point out the fact that selecting top x records without an order by clause is nonsensical.

Comment: @Zohar Peled No, its not nonsensical - it avoids have a huge query do a Denial Of Service attack against your database, what if the user inadvertently triggers a query that would return 100 million rows? Have to limit it to a sane amount, e.g. 32,768 rows but no more.

Comment: @Contango I disagree. it's nonsensical since the order of the records is not guaranteed without using an order by clause. this means that you might not get the results you expect to get.

Comment: @Contango  Actually, I agree with you on that.  I have implemented similar things for websites in the past and the trade-off is not the usual one.  Adding an `ORDER BY` makes it consistent, for a rare/exceptional event, but at the cost of potentially expensive sorting for every query.  Since all the client really needs to know in this situation, is "*are there more rows than I got?*", I usually favor not using ORDER BY in this one case.

Comment: @Zolar Peled The intent of the TOP is to limit results in an emergency situation. If too many results are returned, then something is desperately wrong, and the intent is to limit the damage rather than let the query make SQL Server grind to a halt. In this particular case, adding an ORDER BY is counterproductive as it will slow down normal queries.

Answer (score 5):

Cheat:

```
SELECT TOP 11 * FROM MyTable
```

and check if there are 11 rows :-) Then ignore the eleventh row. Note that from a comment you wrote, perhaps you didn't comprehend: you do this query instead of the `TOP 10` query.

If there are <= 10 rows, then the entire resultset would have been returned by `TOP 10`. If there are 11 rows, then clearly a `TOP 10` wouldn't have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) to get the total number of rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
```

You can check if that result is greater than 10 to determine if it has more than 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can return total number of rows using `count(*)` as extra column.

Something like this:

```
select top 10 T1.*, T2.Total
from MyTable as T1
    outer apply (select count(*) as Total from MyTable) as T2
```